# apache2 does not flushes response data while uploading file

Tags: tomcat, apache2, amazon-elb

Before the question I'll try to give some context.

**The setup**

I have an apache2 (v2.4) server proxying requests with a simple ProxyPass to my local Apache Tomcat (v6).

```
Proxy / http://localhost:8080/
```

**The service**

Our service process one file and when it finishes, sends the status back to the client. Even, with small files, we process the file really slow (intended). So, a single 30kb request can take 5m or so.

**The goal**

To avoid get connections dropped because they are IDLE, we send back every 10s a blank line to the client. So far, so good, even with Amazon ELBs.

So, in the implementation we run the task using a Callable and polling the Future every 10s. When the polling timed out, we send back a blank line to the client and forcing the flush on the outputstream.

**The problem**

But all this stuff works only when the file uploads before the backend sends the first '\n'.

When I send big files (200mb), it takes a few minutes to upload and the client never sees the blank lines, and the connection get dropped when it finishes (because of the idle drop). We tested this requesting directly the Tomcat or the ELB->Tomcat instead of ELB->Apache->Tomcat or Apache->Tomcat and the client receives blank lines successfully.

Comment: A quick look at the httpd docs suggests that httpd will buffer the response by default. I'd try experimenting with the flushpackets option (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) although it looks like you might need to set up a one member balanced config to use it.

Comment: I already did that, it works now (only with proxy_ajp enabled), but I'm facing some weird problems with AJP steadiness: random ioexceptions and broken pipes that never happened with proxy_http.

I've also tried to send over 9k of blank lines to hit the buffer limit and force the apache to flush those bytes, no success so far.